# OpenGL 3.3 Core profile - glDrawArrays fails silently

Tags: c, opengl

I am making use of OpenGL 3.3 and EGL 1.4. The laptop I use to build and run my code (C) makes use of Intel's HD 3000 integrated GPU and runs linux. I thus use the Mesa 3D library. In my program, I create and bind an OpenGL 3.3 core profile compatible context in an X11 window, confirmed by the later returned string of `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, "3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.6".

Next, I use EGL to load various functions of the OpenGL specification (I've opted not to use a library such as GLEW). After doing this, I start setting up OpenGL state to render a run-of-the-mill triangle. I initialize an array of floats which make up the 3 hard-coded vertices of my triangle. Then, I initialize and bind a vertex array object, followed by initializing and binding a vertex buffer object. Finally, I pass my vertex array to glBufferData, to link the vertex data with the vertex buffer object.

```
unsigned int vao;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray(vao);
unsigned int vbo;
  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then, I initialize a basic vertex and fragment shader. Both compile successfully, my shader program links successfully, and validates successfully.

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 p;
void main(){
  gl_Position = vec4(p, 0.0);
}

#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
void main(){
  color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I then proceed to tell GL how to interpret my vertex data;

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Finally, I enter my program's main loop responsible for drawing to and swapping the framebuffer, where bufferloop is `struct timespec bufferloop = (struct timespec){0, 250000};`

```
while(app.running){
  glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  eglSwapBuffers(egldisplay, eglsurface);
  nanosleep(&bufferloop, (void *)0);
}
```

And all I get is a white screen; my triangle is nowhere to be found. I cannot for the life of me determine what the problem is. I have pasted `printf("%d\n", glGetError());` all over my code, and no error is turned up.
`glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);` fails without so much as a peep.

Comment: Are you sure you want `w` to be 0.0 and not 1.0 in your vertex shader?

Comment: You win. If you'd like me to upvote, make a proper answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your vertex shader, the `w` component should be 1 rather than 0. There's a good description from the OpenGL red book [here](http://glprogramming.com/red/appendixf.html) that describes how `w` is used. Briefly:

> OpenGL commands usually deal with two- and three-dimensional vertices, but in fact all are treated internally as three-dimensional homogeneous vertices comprising four coordinates. Every column vector (x, y, z, w)T represents a homogeneous vertex if at least one of its elements is nonzero.
>
> As long as w is nonzero, the homogeneous vertex (x, y, z, w)T corresponds to the three-dimensional point (x/w, y/w, z/w)T. If w = 0.0, it corresponds to no euclidean point, but rather to some idealized "point at infinity." To understand this point at infinity, consider the point (1, 2, 0, 0), and note that the sequence of points (1, 2, 0, 1), (1, 2, 0, 0.01), and (1, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0001), corresponds to the euclidean points (1, 2), (100, 200), and (10000, 20000). This sequence represents points rapidly moving toward infinity along the line 2x = y. Thus, you can think of (1, 2, 0, 0) as the point at infinity in the direction of that line.